# Displaying an image from Sanity block content

Tags: next.js, sanity

I am not able to display images from Sanity's block content. My guess is that I am not retrieving all the data necessary from the 'body' field in my query:

```
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import client from "./sanity.client";

export async function getPage() {
  return client.fetch(
    groq`*[_type == "page"]{
      _id,
      title,
      body[],
    }`
  );
}
```

I have a component to display Sanity data using the url builder like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { PortableText } from '@portabletext/react'
import { getPage } from '../sanity/sanity.query'

import urlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'
import { getImageDimensions } from '@sanity/asset-utils'

// Barebones lazy-loaded image component
const SampleImageComponent = ({ value, isInline }) => {
  console.log('value', value)
  const { width, height } = getImageDimensions(value)
  return (
    <img
      src={urlBuilder()
        .image(value)
        .width(isInline ? 100 : 800)
        .fit('max')
        .auto('format')
        .url()}
      alt={value.alt || ' '}
      loading="lazy"
      style={{
        // Display alongside text if image appears inside a block text span
        display: isInline ? 'inline-block' : 'block',

        // Avoid jumping around with aspect-ratio CSS property
        aspectRatio: width / height,
      }}
    />
  )
}

const components = {
  types: {
    image: SampleImageComponent,
    // Any other custom types you have in your content
    // Examples: mapLocation, contactForm, code, featuredProjects, latestNews, etc.
  },
}

export default () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPageFromSanity = async () => {
      const page = await getPage()
      setPage(page)
    }

    getPageFromSanity()
  }, [])

  console.log(page)
  if (page) {
    console.log('body', page[0].body)
  }

  return (page &&
    <div>
      <h1>Sanity Page</h1>
      {page[0].body &&
        (< PortableText value={page[0].body} components={components} />)
      }
    </div>
```

It results in an error because some data is missing from the url as the image URL has some undefined values:

```
https://cdn.sanity.io/images/undefined/undefined/97d63d851b3ba0ce824730d41d1056015c2bd936-802x1026.png?w=800&fit=max&auto=format
```